# how to Edit a post in rails and display said post in the text_field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to build a page that will host the content of the post from the psql data base and allow user to edit the content of that post inside the text field 
I am getting a no method error however message is the correct column in database
any help is very appreciated

```
<h1>Edit message</h1>

<%= form_with(modle: @post, local: true) do |form| %>
  <p>
    <%= form.label :message %><br>
    <%= form.text_field :message, :value => form.message %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= form.submit %>
  </p>
<%end%>

  <%= link_to 'Back', posts_url %>
```

```
<h1>Posts shown below</h1>
<p>To add a new post click link:
<%= link_to new_post_path do %>
  New post
<% end %>
</p>
<p>---------------------------------------------</p>
<% @posts.reverse_each do |post| %>
  <div id = "<%=post.id %>">
    <p><%= post.message %></p>
    <p><%= post.created_at.strftime(" Posted at %a %I:%M%p") %></p>
    <p><%= link_to 'Destroy', post, :confirm => 'Are you sure?',
                                    :method => :delete %></td>
    <p> <%= link_to 'Update', edit_post_path(post) %> </p>
    <p>---------------------------------------------</p>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: You have a typo in `form_with(model: @post, local: true)`. You don't need to manually bind the value - `<%= form.text_field :message %>` will do it for you. That is the whole point of the point of using a form builder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<h1>Edit message</h1>
<%= form_with(model: @post, local: true) do |form| %>
  <p>
    <%= form.label :message %><br>
    <%= form.text_field :message, :value => Post.find(params[:id]).message %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= form.submit %>
  </p>
<%end%>
<%= link_to 'Back', posts_path %>
```

Comment: This is working and letting me see post content in the text box for edits any refactors are helpful

Comment: You don't need to do this, it's a very bad practice, have you tried the second approach in my answer, just give it a try?

Comment: I did try the second one in your answer and it returned a blank text box for me

Comment: Weird, then you should definitely go with the first one, reason being, you are running another query just to fetch something from db which is already there in the object, `form.object.message` should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

It should be `form.object.message`, make changes in this line

```
<%= form.text_field :message, :value => form.object.message %>
```

or as `max` said, just remove the `value` option all together, it will still work

```
<%= form.text_field :message %>
```

Give it a try!

Comment: Or just do `<%= form.text_field :message %>`. There is absolutely no reason to do it manually here.

Comment: @max Correct, I mistakenly overlooked and assumed it was a `text_field_tag`, thanks!

Comment: Thank you this is helpful ! using Rajdeep post I think im a bit closer. I was trying to set it manually as I want the user to be able to edit an existing post and see that post in the text field so that they can interact with it - rather then a full overwrite which removing the :value => form.object.message seems to do - so I want to display that value in the field - If im misunderstanding please tell me as removing value is leaving my field blank for me